# How do you curry any javascript function of arbitrary arity?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

Let's say I have some function:

```
function g(a,b,c){ return a + b + c }
```

And I'd like to turn it into its "curried" form (in quotations since it's not exactly curried per se):

```
function h(a,b,c){

    switch(true){

        case (a !== undefined && b !== undefined && c !== undefined):
            return a + b + c

        case (a !== undefined && b !== undefined && c === undefined): 
            return function(c){ return a + b + c }

        case (a !== undefined && b == undefined  && c === undefined ):
            return function(b,c){
                return (c === undefined) ? function(c){ return a + b + c } : a + b + c
            }

        default:
            return h

    }

}
```

The above form has the partial binding behavior I want:

```
h(1)     -> h(b,c)
h(1,2)   -> h(c)
h(1,2,3) -> 6
h()      -> h(a,b,c)
```

Now I'd like to automate this process into some generic function `curry` such that given any un-curried function (and maybe its number of parameters), the above function is generated. But I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Alternatively, if the following form could be automatically created, it'd be also interesting:

```
function f(a,b,c){
    return function(a){ return function(b){ return function(c){ return a + b + c }}}
}
```

Though binding `f` looks like this:

```
f(1)(2)(3) = 6
```

so it is very unwieldily and non-idiomatic, but creating the above form seem more feasible to me.

Now is could any of the above form be generated by some function, if so, how?

Comment: lo-dash has already figured this one out. See http://lodash.com/docs#curry. Can you just use that?

Comment: You can’t, really, in general — arguments in JavaScript aren’t required. What will you do with optional arguments?

Comment: @minitech You can tell skipped arguments apart from specified arguments by checking if the arguments are `undefined`. So though JS doesn’t check at compile-time that the argument list is long enough, it’s easy enough to check that at run-time, and behave differently depending on how many arguments are specified.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: `function dIsOptional(a, b, c, d) { … }` `var c = curry(dIsOptional); c(1, 2, 3); // ???`

Comment: @ChrisMontgomery amazing library, I have been using underscore and didn't know this existed

Comment: @chibro2 It would be nice to tell me what's wrong with my answer so that it can be accepted ;) Have you looked at it?

Comment: @plalx hey man I accepted your answer because it definitely works. But I ended up using `_.curry` from lo-dash instead per chris' suggestion, since the library has so many useful things in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you could simply use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). That gives you all the flexibility you need, wheter you want the result of the function right away or simply push another value into the arguments until you decide to execute.

```
function sum() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function (c, n) {
        return c + n;
    });
}

sum(1, 2); //3

var sum2 = sum.bind(null, 1, 2);

sum2(); //3

var sum3 = sum2.bind(null, 3);

sum3(); //6
```

You could also use a helper function like:

```
function curry(fn) {
    var c = curry.bind(this, fn = fn.bind.apply(fn, [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1))));

    c.exec = fn;

    return c;
}

curry(sum, 1, 2)(3)(4, 5)(6, 7, 8).exec(); //36
```

Also this is very flexible as you do not have to chain, you can re-use the same curried function.

```
var sumOnePlus = curry(sum, 1);

sumOnePlus.exec(2); //3;
sumOnePlus.exec(3); //4;
```

Comment: @Bergi What do you think about this?

Comment: The second one looks very good (but should be made less complex code), the first one (`bind`) is unfortunately just partial application not currying.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt:

```
function curry(fn, len) {
    if (typeof len != "number")
        len = fn.length; // getting arity from function
    return function curried() {
        var rlen = len - arguments.length;
        if (rlen <= 0) // then execute now
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        // else create curried, partially bound function:
        var bargs = [this]; // arguments for `bind`
        bargs.push.apply(bargs, arguments);
        return curry(fn.bind.apply(fn, bargs), rlen);
    };
}
```

This does not [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) (which is easy in JS with the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)), but true functional [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). It works with any functions of arbitrary, but fixed arity. For variadic functions you would need a different execution trigger, maybe when no arguments are passed any more or an `exec` method like in @plalx' answer.

Comment: Is "true functional currying" more useful than mere partial application (via `bind`) in JavaScript?  Can I do something with this `curry` function that I could not do via `bind`?  Or if I can't do anything new with `curry`, can I do something more clearly than with `bind` (i.e. is the syntax better)?  I have a rough idea of the distinction between currying and partial application; I am now trying to understand whether it's a _useful_ distinction for actually writing JS.

Comment: @NoahFreitas Yes, it's different, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application. If you partially apply a functions, you are passing the arguments to be bound to the `partial` call. If you curry a function, you don't pass any arguments, but you only get back a function that automatically partially applies itself when needed. The distinction is important, which one of them is more *useful* in actual js depends on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It might help me better understand if you could provide an example where you have chosen to use this `curry` function over `Function.prototype.bind`.  I also realize that this is probably asking much too much for a comment.

Comment: @NoahFreitas: You might want to take a look at [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). All their functions are curried.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function makeLazy(fn) {
    var len = fn.length;
    var args = [];
    return function lazy() {
        args.push.apply(args, arguments);
        if (args.length < len) {
            return lazy;
        } else {
            return fn.apply(this, args);
        }
    }
}

function f(a,b,c) { return a + b + c; }

var lazyF = makeLazy(f);
lazyF(1)(2)(3); // 6

var lazyF = makeLazy(f);
lazyF(1,2)(3); // 6
```

---

If you wanted a reusable function *(I guess I can't tell exactly what you want)*, then this would work:

```
function makeCurry(fn) {
    return function curry() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return function() {
            return fn.apply(this, args.concat.apply(args, arguments));
        };
    }
}


function f(a,b,c) { return a + b + c; }

var curryF = makeCurry(f);
var addOneTwoAnd = curryF(1,2);

addOneTwoAnd(3); // 6
addOneTwoAnd(6); // 9
```

Comment: That wouldn't really work, because then you're sharing `args` across all functions resulting from a given call to `makeLazy`. For example, if `f` takes two arguments, then `var g = makeLazy(f); g(1); g(2); g(3)` is equivalent to `f(1, 2); f(1, 2, 3)`, which is not at all intuitive.

Comment: @ruakh: Yeah, I see what you mean now. I was misinterpreting what OP was after. Seemed like lazy evaluation at first, but now I see OP does just want to curry any number of args. Updated, but left the original answer for the curious.

Comment: @ruakh What do you think of my implementation of `curry`?

Answer (score 0):

The `bind()` method on function lets you bind the `this` inside the function as well as bind extra parameters.  So, if you pass `null` for the `this` parameter, you can use `bind()` to curry the parameters into the function.

```
function g(a,b,c){ return a + b + c }

var g_1 = g.bind(null, 1);
console.log(g_1(2, 3)); // Prints 6

var g_1_2 = g.bind(null, 1, 2);
console.log(g_1_2(3)); // Prints 6
```

Check [Javascript Function bind()](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) for details and interactive examples of using `bind()` to bind parameters.

Comment: Is it me or you have the same answer as mine?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [curry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curry) library.

It can turn any function into curry no matter how many arguments are there.

Example:

```
> var curry = require('curry');
undefined
> var add = curry(function(a, b, c, d, e) { return a + b + c + d + e; });
undefined
> add(1)
[Function]
> add(1,2,3,4,5)
15
> add(1,2)(3,4)(5)
15
>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will cover all scenarios,

```
   function curry(func) {
      return function curried(...args) {
        if (args.length >= func.length) {
          return func(...args);
        } else {
          return function (...next) {
            return curried(...args, ...next);
          };
        }
      };
    }

const sum = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;
const res = curry(sum);
console.log(res(2)(3)(4), "result");
```