# How to pass a parameter with function signature

Tags: javascript

I  don't have a control over the function invocation and I need to pass a few parameters with a pointer. Is it possible to do it?

```
var a = function(a, b){
 return a + b;
}

b = a; //parameter here???
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify? It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I agree this is not clear. Was the purpose to choose `a` for the function 'name' as well? If not then I suspect that you'd be interested in *creating a [proxy] closure* which are discussed in [Eloquent JavaScript: Higher-Order Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html).

Comment: It is just an example. 'b' should  be invoked with parameters

Comment: What 'parameters'? And please *choose better variable names*, unless the duplicate names are supposed to mean something; and if they are, explain it in more detail.

Comment: In your last line, the use of `b` is confusing, since you could use any name there. The correct way to pass parameters to a is to replace your last line with : `b = a(1, 2);`  This will give you `3`(stored into `b`, which you can see by running `console.log(b);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use currying, the outer function call will return a pointer to another function that references the parameters you passed. Then you can call the inner function without passing the parameters.

```
var a = function(x, y) {
   function(){
      return x + y;
   }
}

b = a(2, 3); 
b();
```

Comment: I think introducing currying to the asker at this point is a bit too early, especially without references to the technique or explanations.

Comment: maybe you are right, I will give some explanation, but I think this is what he wants

Comment: @nha I'm having some trouble here explaining this an easy way, can you help ?

Comment: Well this is not an easy concept, clearly one needs to understand `closures` and `higher order functions`. Then this post explains it in a context close to the original questoin, so that may be of some help https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/curry-cooking-up-tastier-functions/

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass parameters to a is to replace your last line with : `b = a(1, 2);`.

This will give you `3` as a result, stored into the variable `b`.
You can see the current value of `b` at any time by running `console.log(b);` :

```
var a = function(a, b){
 return a + b;
}

b = a(1, 2);    // parameters here 

console.log(b); // prints 3
```

But as I said, the use of `b` twice here is confusing. A better naming would be :

```
// sum is a better name
var sum = function(a, b){
 return a + b;
}

result = sum(1, 2);  // parameters here : 1 corresponds to a, 2 to b

console.log(result); // prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself. I am sorry if the question is not clear enough.

This is what I needed.

```
var a = function(a, b) {
    return function(){
        console.log(a + b);
    }
};

b = a(3, 4); 
b();
```

Comment: This is not a correct solution. If you are looking for a currying function to add numbers, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042221/how-do-you-curry-any-javascript-function-of-arbitrary-arity

Comment: @andrey I forgot to mention : it may take some time to sink in (at least it did for me), that's normal. Don't get discouraged, just take it piece by piece.