# How can I create 1 or 2 higher order functions / closures as a alternative to a class with methods?

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create higher order functions in a nice way for a function named `someFn`, I got it to work with a class kind of

```js
const fn = (ctx, a, ...rest) => {};

class A {
  constructor(ctx, opts) {
    Object.assign(this, opts);
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  someMethod(a, ...rest) {
    return fn(this.ctx, a, ...rest);
  }
}

const a = new A(ctx, opts);
someFn("something", (b) => a.someMethod.bind(a, b));
```

I was wondering how I can write this and get the exact same behaviour with using functions only, no class, and have a call style like

```js
someFn("something", withProxy(doThis))
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of that class? Is that your actual code? Are you using the instance `a` more than once? Where do `ctx` and `opts` in the `new A` call come from? What is `doThis` supposed to be, how is that equivalent to your first snippet?

Comment: Put otherwise: you can trivially get rid of that class by writing `someFn("something", (b) => (...args) => fn(ctx, b, ...args))` directly.

Comment: `opts` does not seem to serve a purpose...

Comment: Can I create a higher order function that accepts the ctx and options and passes those with the args to another function I can call inside? I would like to have a wrap(fn) call style, I might use opts later @Bergi, the class is what I actually have now but with more clear names, my actual function call would ideally be `decorate("aMethodName", withProxy(getCompletionsProxy))`

Comment: @Daniell You want to get rid of classes yet you still speak of methods. I really don't understand what you want to decorate there. Also if you want the function to accept ctx and options, where are you passing these in `decorate("aMethodName", withProxy(getCompletionsProxy))`?

Comment: The decorate function would be a 3rd party function that exposes "b" as callback, maybe withProxy could be a function like `const withProxy = (ctx, opts) => {}` and then continue from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The higher-order function you seem to be looking for might be

```
const fn = (ctx, a, ...rest) => {};
const fnCurried = (ctx) => (b) => (...rest) => fn(ctx, b, ...rest);
```

to be used as

```
someFn("something", fnCurried(ctx));
```

Comment: Can this be split with another level? So that fn can be called inside fnCurried? Basically `const fnCurried = createContext(ctx)` and `someFn("", fnCurried(fn))`

Comment: Yes, read up on currying and partial application. `const fnCurried = curry(fn)` is possible, but it's more instructive to see the nested function expressions first. And of course you can also swap around the parameters so that you bind the context first and the function later.

Comment: Would you be able to create an edit with that? It was actually what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @Daniell Take [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068091/1048572) for example, but there's a lot of implementations out there. Swapping parameters is as simple as `const flip = fn => a => b => fn(b)(a)`. But I really would recommend to use curried notations (nested arrow functions) for the definition of `fn` in the first place, much simpler to use and understand.